WPF - Cannot override ScrollViewer scroll bars style
Looking at this doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
I copied the whole style to my style sheet and I set all colors to red to spot if any change is applied to the default scroll bars in my scroll viewers
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">red</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">red</Color>

and removed the key of the style so it applies for all scroll bars
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation"
             Value="Horizontal">
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="Auto" />
      <Setter Property="Height"
              Value="18" />
      <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation"
             Value="Vertical">
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="18" />
      <Setter Property="Height"
              Value="Auto" />
      <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

but it does not display anywhere in my scroll viewers
any help appreciated

By "style sheet" you mean resource dictionary? Are you not merging it in app.xaml?

I am willing to change all colors, not just the thumb, and that style comes from microsoft itself, looking at it, it is supposed to change all colors...of any scroll bar. I found a couple of other answers, none of them work

I refer to style sheet as from html web, sorry about that, my style resource directory is working and in place for other components, so it should be taken into account here

Have you checked actual Styles of ScrollBar? The ones you linked are no longer used.

where can I get an updated version ?
